# Python: Attribute inheritance through '__init__'

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes, init

Suppose I have a code as follows:

```
class Attribute:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1

    def add_one(self):
        self.value += 1


class Space:

    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = Attribute()

    def along(self, axis):
        return Axis(self.attribute , axis)


class Axis:

    def __init__(self, attribute, axis):
        self.attribute = attribute
        self.axis = axis

    def foo(self):
        self.attribute.add_one()
```

Coming from Matlab, I am new to Python and I still don't quite understand how instances are managed.
What I have noticed is that if I run the following:

```
space = Space()
space.along("x").foo()

print(space.along("x").attribute.value, space.attribute.value)
# OUT: 2 2
```

I would expect that only `space.along("x").attribute.value` is modified but instead the change also affects `space.attribute.value` , even if it comes from a different class.

My questions is:
I define an instance of `Attribute()` inside `Space()` class. When this is passed to `Axis()` through `__init__`, the instance itslef is passed, rather than the general class. Is this correct?

Thank you

Comment: The `Axis` object holds a reference to the same instance of `Attribute` that the `Space` object does. (I.e., `space.attribute is  space.along("foo").attribute` is true. )Give https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html a read to understand what is going on.

Comment: Also, you are not using inheritance in any point there. But yes, once you have a reference to an object, that will be the same object.

If you were really using `inhertance` the child class would eventually run the code in its parent's `__init__` and that would create a new `Attribute` instance, when the line  containing `Attribute()` gets executed. Not otherwise.